# Access current module name in built vue3/vite application

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, rollupjs, vite

In my vue3/vite/typescript application, I use `import.meta.url` and extract the file name to get the name of the current module:

File 'myModule.ts':

```
export default {
  url: import.meta.url
}
```

File 'test.ts':

```
import myModule from "./myModule"

console.log(myModule.url)
```

This works great, as long as I run the development server (which actually imports the modules), but fails if I use the built version. The reason is, that the built version is created with rollup.js which creates a single file and doesn't really import anything anymore.

But how could I possibly get the name of the module in this context? Can I somehow keep `import.meta` work or is there another way to achieve this (other than duplicating the file name in the `url` property)?

Comment: It would be a problem if a bundle were polluted with paths that are specific to a system where it has been built. Rollup can possibly be configured to do this but the most straightforward way is to hardcode a name.

Comment: My use case requires a lot of files which should be easily identifyable by their name, but I need this name as well inside of the corresponding module. In Node.Js, this would be easy by using `__filename`, but this isn't available here just the same.
When doubling the file name inside the module, the risk is that names diverge.

Comment: I'd be happy to be proven otherwise but this Node behaviour is native to it and not generally applicable to other environments, especially browser. As I said, you'll end up with filling up your bundle with considerable amount of unnecessary metadata that cannot be minified and can be sensitive depending on actual path. Probably can be solved in reverse, by using dynamic imports that are provided with module name, can't say how it will affect a bundle in this case. You can also check https://github.com/rollup/rollup/issues/2748

Comment: Thanks, @EstusFlask, the link to the github issue looks very interesting, I hoped for something like that! But in fact, the dynamic import idea seems quite the right thing for my use case - I'll stick to it here.

Comment: The problem with dynamic imports is that they are async, but this may be not an issue depending on your case, also top-level await is already there and can substitute import statement.

Answer (score 0):

Use `getCurrentInstance` this has most of the things the Options API `this` had

```js
import {
  getCurrentInstance
} from 'vue'

export default {
  setup() {
    const instance = getCurrentInstance();
  }
}
```

And do some digging in this object to find the name of your component!

Comment: While this might help in a Vue component, my code is rather in a helper module which is actually used by a vuex action. Regrettably there is no such thing like an vue rendering instance.